# Calculate binomial coffeficient very reliably

Tags: c++, math, binomial-coefficients, gamma-function

What is the best method to calculate a binomial coefficient in C++? I've seen some code fragments but it seemed to me that it is always only doable in some specific region. I need a very, very, very reliable calculation. I tried it with a gamma function:

```
unsigned n=N;
unsigned k=2;
number = tgammal(n + 1) / (tgammal(k + 1) * tgammal(n - k + 1));
```

but it differs already at n=8, k=2 of 1 (and by n=30, k=2 it crashes)..
I "only" need a calculation of about at least n=3000 with k=2.

Comment: How **accurate** does it need to be? `return 1` is very reliable, it's just entirely inaccurate .

Comment: Do you need the value for k=2 only? cause that would sure be very easy

Comment: @MSalters Good question. I just meant the output has to be correct, so I guess therefore I mean accurate?

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 1 +2 in case of a binomial coefficient?

Comment: @HarshitSinghal Yes, only for k=2. How very easy exactly?

Comment: @Ben, Could you please answer? I understand that `1 + 2` isn't a binomial coefficient, but that's irrelevant to the question whether or not you consider this calculation reliable. You're asking for reliable solution, and the term "reliable" isn't clear here, so I cannot be sure that my answer is a good one. Help me help you.

Comment: ans for k=2 would simply be n*(n-1)/2...am i missing something here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This

```
constexpr inline size_t binom(size_t n, size_t k) noexcept
{
    return
      (        k> n  )? 0 :          // out of range
      (k==0 || k==n  )? 1 :          // edge
      (k==1 || k==n-1)? n :          // first
      (     k+k < n  )?              // recursive:
      (binom(n-1,k-1) * n)/k :       //  path to k=1   is faster
      (binom(n-1,k) * n)/(n-k);      //  path to k=n-1 is faster
}
```

requires **O(min{k,n-k})** operations, is reliable and can be done at compile time.

**Explanation** The binomial coefficients are defined as `B(n,k)=k!(n-k)!/n!`, from which we see that `B(n,k)=B(n,n-k)`. We can also obtain the recurrence relations `n*B(n,k)=(n-k)*B(n-1,k)=k*B(n-1,k-1)`. Moreover, the result is trivial for `k=0,1,n,n-1`.

For `k=2`, the result is also trivially `(n*(n-1))/2`.

Of course, you can do that also with other integer types. If you need to know a binomial coefficient which exceeds the largest representable integer type, you must use approximate methods: using `double` instead. In this case, using the gamma function is preferrable

```
#include <cmath>
inline double logbinom(double n, double k) noexcept
{
    return std::lgamma(n+1)-std::lgamma(n-k+1)-std::lgamma(k+1);
}
inline double binom(double n, double k) noexcept
{
    return std::exp(logbinom(n,k));
}
```

Comment: I know it's a while but I came across this solution again and I think I didn't understand how it works or forgot it. How do I get to the formula "(binom(n-1,k-1) * n)/k"? And how can I call a function I'm operating in actually?

Comment: @Ben. I added an explanation for the algebra. The call is recursive: the function calls itself with different argument types. Recursive algorithms are very frequent and allow for some elegance.

Answer (score 4):

You may use asymptotically more effective recurrent formula:

```
constexpr inline size_t binom(size_t n, size_t k) noexcept
{
    return
      (        k> n  )? 0 :          // out of range
      (k==0 || k==n  )? 1 :          // edge
      (k==1 || k==n-1)? n :          // first
      binom(n - 1, k - 1) * n / k;   // recursive
}
```

This will use only **O(k)** operations to calculate C(n, k).

Comment: Is it a strange co-incidence that this code looks almost identical to that in my answer? Even the comments? Only difference is the last line which uses integer division and faster for large k.

Comment: @Walter, The only difference is that I use another recurrent formula: `C(n, k) = n/k * C(n - 1, k - 1)` instead of `C(n, k) = C(n - 1, k - 1) + C(n - 1, k)`. My solution runs in **O(k)** operations, while yours in **O(nk)**. So, I propose ~3000 times faster solution with no cons compared to yours.

Comment: Indeed, my recursion is not good for large `n`. I have adopted your method but improved in case `k>n/2`.